# How can I find the max number in the code?

Tags: java, printing, max

I want my code to print out 10 numbers per line and count how many numbers there are. I also want to be able to find the max number. I am having trouble figuring out how to find the max. Here is my code.

```
int valCount = 0;
int numCount =0;

while (startingNum > 1) {
 int count = 0;
 System.out.print(startingNum + " ");
  valCount++;

  if(valCount%10 ==0)
    System.out.println();
  if (startingNum % 2==0) {
    startingNum = startingNum/2;
    numCount++;
} else {
    startingNum = (startingNum*3) +1; 
    numCount++;
 }
}
```

Comment: You can always add counter for each number, when it is 10, print line separator and reset counter.

Comment: hint: "\n" is the newline character. you can use it like this: hello \nThis is a new line

Comment: or `System.out.println()` to start printing from the new line

Comment: Are you sure that this is **YOUR** code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter, increment it at each print, when you reach a multiple of 10 print a new line, also to align the different elements, I would suggest to use `printf`, here I set to `%5d` because max number has 4 digit, if it goes up to like 6 digit use `%7d`

```
int valCount = 0;
while (startingNum > 1) {
    System.out.printf("%5d", startingNum);
    valCount++;
    if(valCount%10 ==0)
        System.out.println();
    if (startingNum % 2==0) {
        startingNum = startingNum/2;
    } else {
        startingNum = (startingNum*3) +1; 
    }
}
System.out.printf("    1");
```

The [`Demo code`](https://ideone.com/ykESoI) will give you :

```
   27   82   41  124   62   31   94   47  142   71
  214  107  322  161  484  242  121  364  182   91
  274  137  412  206  103  310  155  466  233  700
  350  175  526  263  790  395 1186  593 1780  890
  445 1336  668  334  167  502  251  754  377 1132
  566  283  850  425 1276  638  319  958  479 1438
  719 2158 1079 3238 1619 4858 2429 7288 3644 1822
  911 2734 1367 4102 2051 6154 3077 9232 4616 2308
 1154  577 1732  866  433 1300  650  325  976  488
  244  122   61  184   92   46   23   70   35  106
   53  160   80   40   20   10    5   16    8    4
    2    1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int startingNum = 27;
    int counter = 0;
    while (startingNum > 1) {
        counter++;
        System.out.print(startingNum + " ");
        if (counter % 10 == 0)
            System.out.println();
        if (startingNum % 2 == 0) {
            startingNum = startingNum / 2;
        } else {
            startingNum = (startingNum * 3) + 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(1);
}
```